# Registration not working in magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento

magento 1.9X

I am using below ref to create ajax login/reg popup.
Login works fine. but not able to register.

http://fastdivision.com/2012/03/29/diy-magento-create-ajax-login-registration-forms-for-your-magento-theme/
It gives same error popup "Please make sure your passwords match". even if i use existing email.same popup error appears.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <FastDivision_QuickLogin>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </FastDivision_QuickLogin>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <FastDivision_QuickLogin before="Mage_Customer">FastDivision_QuickLogin_Customer</FastDivision_QuickLogin>
                    <!--<FastDivision_QuickLogin before="Mage_Customer_Account">FastDivision_QuickLogin_Customer</FastDivision_QuickLogin>
                    <FastDivision_QuickLogin before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">FastDivision_QuickLogin_Customer</FastDivision_QuickLogin>-->
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

AccountController.php

```
<?php
// Require the core controller file that you're planning to override
require_once('Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php');

// The class name follows this format:
// YOURPACKAGE_YOUREXTENSION_COREMODULEFOLDER_CONTROLLERFILENAME
// We extend the original Mage_Customer_AccountController class to inherit unused actions and override specific actions
class FastDivision_QuickLogin_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
// Code referenced from AccountController.php
public function loginPostAction()
{
    if(!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
    }

    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        // Report exceptions via JSON
        $ajaxExceptions = array();
    }

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                    $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                    foreach ($messages as $message) {
                        $ajaxExceptions['exceptions'][] = $message;
                    }
                } else {
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $value = Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                            $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    $session->addError($message);
                }

                $session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
            }
        } else {
            if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                $ajaxExceptions['exceptions'][] = 'Login and password are required.';
            } else {
                $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
            }
        }
    }

    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        // If errors
        if(count($ajaxExceptions)) {
            echo json_encode($ajaxExceptions);
        } else {
            // No Errors
            echo json_encode(array('success' => 'success'));
        }
    } else {
        // Redirect for non-ajax
        $this->_loginPostRedirect();
    }
}

// Create Account
public function createPostAction()
{
    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        // Report exceptions via JSON
        $ajaxExceptions = array();
    }

    $session = $this->_getSession();
    if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session->setEscapeMessages(true); // prevent XSS injection in user input
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $errors = array();

        if (!$customer = Mage::registry('current_customer')) {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setId(null);
        }

        /* @var $customerForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
        $customerForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
        $customerForm->setFormCode('customer_account_create')
            ->setEntity($customer);

        $customerData = $customerForm->extractData($this->getRequest());

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
            $customer->setIsSubscribed(1);
        }

        /**
         * Initialize customer group id
         */
        $customer->getGroupId();

        if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('create_address')) {
            /* @var $address Mage_Customer_Model_Address */
            $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
            /* @var $addressForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
            $addressForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
            $addressForm->setFormCode('customer_register_address')
                ->setEntity($address);

            $addressData    = $addressForm->extractData($this->getRequest(), 'address', false);
            $addressErrors  = $addressForm->validateData($addressData);
            if ($addressErrors === true) {
                $address->setId(null)
                    ->setIsDefaultBilling($this->getRequest()->getParam('default_billing', false))
                    ->setIsDefaultShipping($this->getRequest()->getParam('default_shipping', false));
                $addressForm->compactData($addressData);
                $customer->addAddress($address);

                $addressErrors = $address->validate();
                if (is_array($addressErrors)) {
                    $errors = array_merge($errors, $addressErrors);
                }
            } else {
                $errors = array_merge($errors, $addressErrors);
            }
        }

        try {
            $customerErrors = $customerForm->validateData($customerData);
            if ($customerErrors !== true) {
                $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
            } else {
                $customerForm->compactData($customerData);
                $customer->setPassword($this->getRequest()->getPost('password'));
                $customer->setConfirmation($this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation'));
                $customerErrors = $customer->validate();
                if (is_array($customerErrors)) {
                    $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
                }
            }

            $validationResult = count($errors) == 0;

            if (true === $validationResult) {
                $customer->save();

                Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
                    array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
                );

                if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
                    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
                        'confirmation',
                        $session->getBeforeAuthUrl(),
                        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
                    );
                    $session->addSuccess($this->__('Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail())));

                    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                        echo json_encode(array('success' => $this->__('Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail()))));
                    } else {
                        $this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure'=>true)));
                    }

                    return;
                } else {
                    $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer);

                    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                        echo json_encode(array('success' => 'success'));
                    } else {
                        $this->_redirectSuccess($url);
                    }

                    return;
                }
            } else {
                $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());

                if(!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                    if (is_array($errors)) {
                        foreach ($errors as $errorMessage) {
                            $session->addError($errorMessage);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $session->addError($this->__('Invalid customer data'));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (is_array($errors)) {
                        foreach ($errors as $errorMessage) {
                            $ajaxExceptions['exceptions'][] = $errorMessage;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $ajaxExceptions['exceptions'][] = 'Invalid customer data';
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if ($e->getCode() === Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS) {
                $url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.', $url);
                $session->setEscapeMessages(false);
            } else {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }

            if(!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                $session->addError($message);
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $ajaxExceptions['exceptions'][] = $message;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if(!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
            } else {
                $ajaxExceptions['exceptions'][] = 'Cannot save the customer.';
            }
        }
    }

    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        echo json_encode($ajaxExceptions);
    } else {
        $this->_redirectError(Mage::getUrl('*/*/create', array('_secure' => true)));
    }
}
}
```

quick_login.phtml

```
    <div id="login-modal" class="modal-window">
  <div id="login-modal-content">
    <div id="signup-box">
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <p><a href="#" id="already-registered-link">Already registered? Click here to sign in.</a></p>

  <form action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>customer/account/createpost/" method="post" id="signup-form" class="site-form" onsubmit="return false">
    <ul class="form-list">
      <li class="fields">
          <div class="field first-field">
              <label for="firstname" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('First Name') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <div class="input-box">
                  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
              <label for="last_name" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Last Name') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <div class="input-box">
                  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
              <label for="email_address" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Email') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <div class="input-box">
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
              <label for="password" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <div class="input-box">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
              <label for="confirmation" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <div class="input-box">
                  <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button type="submit" title="Submit" class="action-button"><span>Create Account</span></button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="login-box">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <p><?php echo $this->__('If you have an account with us, please log in.') ?></p>
  <p><a href="#" id="need-account-link">Need an account? Click here to register.</a></p>

  <form action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>customer/account/loginPost/" method="post" id="login-form" class="site-form" onsubmit="return false">
    <ul class="form-list">
         <li class="field">
             <label for="email" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Email') ?><em>*</em></label>
             <div class="input-box">
                 <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
             </div>
         </li>
         <li class="field">
             <label for="pass" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?><em>*</em></label>
             <div class="input-box">
                 <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
             </div>
         </li>
     </ul>

      <button type="submit" class="action-button action-button-no-arrow" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="small"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a>
       </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="close_x" class="close" href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
  //]]>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide url where you have tried this

Comment: and you did not post your phtml

Comment: i have tried on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Magento 1.9 whenever a customer checkouts or registers in storefront, “Please make sure your password match” pop up comes even if your password and confirm password fields are same. In Magento version 1.9, to Validate confirm password values in class “Mage_Customer_Model_Customer” method validate()  was changed a bit.

Before:

```
 $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
```

After:

```
$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
```

So if you are getting the same issue while checkout and registration, change the line to

```
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from the error you are receiving, the issue is triggered by the missing 'Password Confirmation' form.

Even if you have decided to hide it, you have to use it in order to duplicate the password in the Controller, until user's validation occurs  before saving.

Check data at the exit of the createPostAction method:

```
var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost());
```

or via Debug (if you are using it).

The array should have the following view: 
https://gyazo.com/52d5c7fe80316b9f8f3773fcfa1f6462

This is the minimum of the required parameters (those that are filled in).

If the array doesn't contain the element with the confirmation key and the meaning that corresponds to the password, it will be ignored and skipped somewhere at your template (.phtml).

If it still present there, you should check the whole set of implemented actions in createPostAction and find the spot, where it is deleted before calling Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::validate() (the is the place, where the error is generated).

If you are sending the form without using AJAX and using the Submit option, you should delete this form attribute

```
 onsubmit="return false;"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.it helped me. i found below article which helped me.

Comment: i changed  $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation(); TO   $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation(); in Mage_Customer_Model_Customer inside validate method.

Comment: will it cause any problem in future. i am new to magento.